# Insertar un string en un input y que no se pueda modificar. en php o javascript

Tags: javascript, php, input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una duda, quiero intentar poner un string en un input tipo text por defecto este string '_en' o '_re' pero que este string no se puede modificar y que quede en el input por defecto, antes de este string en el input que se pueda escribir, EJEMPLO : A1_en o A2_re no se si hay que hacer una función.. muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes?

Comment: Agrega al  `input` el atributo `readonly`-

Comment: @a.Cedano hola, lo que quiero hacer te dejo un foto.. quizás me entiendas un poco mejor

Comment: @juanCarlosGuibovich claro lo que quiero es en '_re' o '_en' sea solo lectura que no se pueda modificar pero que antes de ese string que el usuario pueda ingresar cualquier caracter.. subi una foto a la publicación de ejemplo

Comment: Veo complicado y poco práctico hacer esto en el mismo input. ¿Por qué no usas otro elemento a modo de sufijo donde pongas el `_re`  o el `_en` y unes ese valor y lo que el usuario escriba de forma programática? Si interesa que *parezcan* un mismo input lo puedes hacer mediante reglas CSS. Pero para fines prácticos y demás querer mantener esto en un solo input lo veo complicado, tendrás que recurrir a trucos oscuros para impedir que el usuario escriba en una parte de tu input.

Comment: Cuando quieras que sea de solo lectura le agregas por script el atributo `readonly` al `input`. Por otro lado, opino igual que A.Cedano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo crearía un input independiente para los sufijos `_en` y `_re` y luego uniría los valores por programación.

Es la forma más simple de lograr lo que pretendes. Si metes todo en un input tendrás que recurrir a métodos oscuros y complicados para evitar que el usuario escriba en una parte de tu input (lo que sería el sufijo), mientras que aquí el usuario no podrá acceder nunca porque el elemento del sufijo está deshabilitado.

Si quieres refinar la vista, puedes recurrir a reglas CSS para hacer los dos inputs como si fuera una solo, eso es relativamente fácil.

Aquí un ejemplo. En el evento `change` verás que los valores se unen, usando [`nextElementSibiling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) para obtener el valor del input del sufijo.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.two input');

divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', event => {
  var mSufix = el.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(`${el.value}${mSufix.value}`);
}));
```

```css
.two input {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="two">
  <input id="inputEn" value="" placeholder="Escriba valor para _en" />
  <input type="text" value="_en" size="1" disabled/>
  <input id="inputRe" value="" placeholder="Escriba valor para _re" />
  <input type="text" value="_re" size="1" disabled/>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesante.. gracias por el aporte! lo voy a ver con mas detalle, seguramente lo implemente para ver como queda!